# Finding the n'th $(n\geq2)$ derivative of the equation $\frac{x^3}{2x^2 - x - 3}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I tried spotting some pattern after derivating it a few times, but I couldn't find any. Maybe I should use the Leibniz formula somehow?

Comment: Hint;  partial fractions.

Comment: oh, completely forgot about them, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polynomial long division gives:

$$\frac{x^3}{2x^2 - x - 3} = \frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\frac{7}{4}x+\frac{3}{4}}{2x^2-x-3}$$

and now use partial fractions on the last term:

$$\frac{1}{4} \frac{7x+3}{(2x-3)(x+1)} = \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{A}{2x-3} + \frac{B}{x+1} \right)$$
$$A(x+1) + B(2x-3) = 7x+3$$
$$x = -1 \Rightarrow B = \frac{4}{5} \ ; \ x = \frac{3}{2} \Rightarrow A = \frac{27}{5}$$

and therefore:
$$\frac{x^3}{2x^2 - x - 3} = \frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{27/5}{2x-3} +  \frac{4/5}{x+1} \right)$$

Treat the first derivative as a special case. All other derivatives can be found using the power rule and chain rule.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wanted to post my solution, but I was short on time.

Comment: @RainCatalyst No problem!